# Стоит ли всегда при создании Node.js-приложений заменять обратные слэши в путях на прямые?

Tags: node.js, gulp, кроссплатформенность

Однажды, мой [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar)-объект для наблюдения за файлами (обёрнутый в `gulp.watch()`) перестал работать. После длительной отладки и экспериментов я обнаружил, что причиной являются обратные слэши в glob-выражениях:

```js
gulp.watch([
  'C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\0_Development\\1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)',
  'C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\1_Open\\1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)'
])
```

(Естественно, что приведённые выше абсолютные пути вручную я не прописывал, а программно определял и программно формировал glob-выборки).

У меня практически нет опыта работы в UNIX-подобных системах, но я хочу, чтобы мои приложения работали кроссплатформенно. Если приведённый **ниже** код работает и в Windows, и в Linux, и Mac OS, то мне остаётся сделать предположение, при при написании кроссплатформенных приложений на Node.js **всегда** следует **избегать** обратных слэшей в путях - так безопаснее всего. Верно ли моё предположение?

```js
gulp.watch([
  'C:/Users/i/projects/test/1_Source/0_Development/1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)',
  'C:/Users/i/projects/test/1_Source/1_Open/1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)'
])
```

И ещё: я заметил, что `path.normalize()` не всегда даёт желаемый результат. Верно ли то предположение, что `.replace(/\\/g, '/')` - **единственный** способ **гарантировать** отсутствие обратных косых черт в путях?

---

### Обновление: результаты новых экспериментов

Ни один из следующих наблюдателей не работает:

```js
// --- 1
gulp.watch([
  'C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\0_Development\\1_Markup\\**\\*.+(pug)',
  'C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\1_Open\\1_Markup\\**\\*.+(pug)'
])

// --- 2
gulp.watch([
  path.normalize('C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\0_Development\\1_Markup\\**\\*.+(pug)'),
  path.normalize('C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\1_Open\\1_Markup\\**\\*.+(pug)')
])

// --- 3
gulp.watch([
  'C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\0_Development\\1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)',
  'C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\1_Open\\1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)'
])

// --- 4
gulp.watch([
  path.normalize('C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\0_Development\\1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)'),
  path.normalize('C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\1_Open\\1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)')
])
```

А этот - по-прежнему работает.

```js
gulp.watch([
  'C:/Users/i/projects/test/1_Source/0_Development/1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)',
  'C:/Users/i/projects/test/1_Source/1_Open/1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)'
])
```

Comment: Результат `path.normalize()` зависит от того, на какой операционной системе запущена нода.

Comment: @Yaant Это я уже понял. Но, как показал эксперимент из обновления к вопросу, обратные слэши ненадёжны, а потому стоит вопрос, стоит ли их избегать и в Windows, тоже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gulp принимает не системные пути до файлов, а так называемые глобы (glob). Глобы не поддерживают символ `\` как разделитель, это для них символ экранирования. Поэтому нужно использовать всегда символ `/`.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Я правильно понял, что символ '/' - универсальный для Windows, Linux и Mac, и в '\' нужды при использовании в путях вообще нет (по крайней мере, при программировании на Node.js)?

Comment: @БоковГлеб в общем-то, да.